# Remove dotted border from dialog box when click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this problem :

I have a dialog box that I open through JQuery and everithing goes fine, but when I click on it, a thin dotted line appears around the div that contains the dialog box (I have two buttons so this append every time). I would like to remove this line via Jquery or Css, it doesn't matter, I just don't want it to shows.

I think i have to override some css class from dialog box, but I can't figure out wich one.

Thanks.

Comment: can you give any fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use CSS:

```
.button-selector {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Insure !important is appended to none to ensure it never appears if the above code is not working.

Comment: @DeanMeehan - !important should always be avoided in favour of better specificity

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to your advice I managed what I want.
I've just to set

```
.ui-widget-content {
    outline: none;
}
```